# Problems with positioning footers using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm having a problem placing footers on my document. On the first page it shows ok, but in the next pages it doesn't show at all. A bit of thinkering made me realize that the footer was indeed appearing, but out of page boundaries, so it wasn't visible. So the question is, how can I fix the height at which the footer is expected to appear? my code (part of it) is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
.......
\usepackage[margin=4.5cm,headheight=28pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
.......
\hoffset-2.8cm
\voffset-2.3cm
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{22.5cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\fancyhead[C]{
    \hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}b{12cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
        % & \\[0.05ex]
        \hspace*{0.5cm}\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo.png} & \hspace*{-2.5cm} Some random text I need... & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{LogoONAC.png} \\
    \end{tabular}   
}
\fancyfoot[C]{ - Some text I need to appear as footer on every page - }
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Ok, so I've reproduced my problem as suggested by Werner. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,headheight=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{
    \hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}b{12cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
        % & \\[0.05ex]
        \hspace*{0.5cm}\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo.png} & \hspace*{-2.5cm}\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b{17cm}} \\[5ex] \textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\ \textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\ \textbf{\footnotesize XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\ \end{tabular} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{LogoONAC.png} \\
    \end{tabular}   
}

\fancyfoot[C]{ - OPERADOR - }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a a compilable document, not just fragments. And remove those `......` in the preamble, they cause errors. I am pretty sure you have to change the `\footskip` length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need to change in your code:

- Don't set the page layout with [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and then add other page layout settings manually. Do one or the other.

  I'd suggest using and sticking with only `geometry` and leave out settings like this:

  ```
  \hoffset-2.8cm
  \voffset-2.3cm
  \setlength{\textwidth}{18cm}
  \setlength{\textheight}{22.5cm}
  ```
- You're probably trying to create a somewhat contradictory situation in terms of the page layout. Setting `margin=4.5cm` and having a `\textwidth` set to `22.5cm` doesn't make it fit within a `letterpaper` size.
- Listen to the warning issued by [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

  ```
  Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (28.0pt): 
   Make it at least 116.60004pt.
   We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
   This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
  ```

  The value following "Make it at least ..." may differ depending on the size of the actual images you're including. This might be the root cause of your problem, as thing are adjusted for all pages following the first.

Here is a toned-down version of your example code where I've removed any manual setting of the page layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=4.5cm,headheight=68pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a}\ Some random text I need...}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\fancyfoot[C]{ - Some text I need to appear as footer on every page - }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've made those changes, but my document's layout got screwed. See the edited content on the question. BTW, thank you ;)

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez: Look at the third bullet in my answer; you have the same issue on your end. Look at your `.log` and see what [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) suggests in terms of `\headheight`. If it says it should be at least `123.4567pt`, then make it `124pt`. That is, use `headheight=124pt` as part of your setting for [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Once you've correctly set the header height, other things will fall into place.

Comment: It says to set it to 93 something, so I set it to 94. Now the header is almost completely hidden :S
The layout is consistent though, but I can't use it without the header.
http://imgur.com/37xrrHk

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez: Okay, use `margin=1.cm,top=X` where you see adjust `X` to suit your needs. That'll push down the header into position. You can even do `top=\dimexpr1.5cm+94pt`.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you very much!! I'd get you a beer, but I guess we're pretty far away ;)