# Why do each of the pages after the first drop down a little?

Tags: spacing

I tried to do a custom header on the first page and then just a regular footer on every page by copying things from other people's questions.  But when I compile the first page looks fine but all the ones after that have too big of a top margin and too small of a bottom margin.  How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry} \usepackage{times}
\geometry{top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in}

\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{} 
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle} {
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Firstie McLastName \\ Subject \\ SubSubject}
\fancyhead[R]{Word Count: \#}
\fancyfoot[C]{1}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%To make sure we actually have header 0.5in away from top edge
%12pt is one-sixth of an inch. Subtract this from 0.5in to get headsep value
\setlength\headsep{0.333in}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

\thispagestyle{firststyle}

$ $\\
\begin{center}
\underline{Title}
\end{center}

%%%%Changes paragraph indentation to 0.5in
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was just addressed here: [Problems with positioning footers using `fancyhdr`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311654/5764)

Comment: The main problem arises from an incorrect setting of `headheight` since you're using a construction with line-breaks. As such, it's not the expected `12pt` anymore, but should rather be at least `41.53389pt` (check your `.log`). Use `margin=1in, headheight=42pt, top=\dimexpr1in+42pt` as your [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) settings and peace will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

You get the following warning:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 41.53389pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Use

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  letterpaper,
  top=1.0in,
  bottom=1.0in,
  left=1.0in,
  right=1.0in,
  headsep=0.333in,
  headheight=42pt,
}
```

(don't set `\headsep` outside the options to `\geometry`).